# How to find out double word count in hadoop using mapreduce with java

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need mapreduce code in java to find out double word count solution in hadoop

input :

"what is your name ? what you want from me ?
 You know best way to earn money is Hardwork 
 what is your aim ?"

Double W.C. Output :
what is 2
is your 2
your name 1
what you 1

a quicker response is very much appreciable.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The below code works for me.

```
package hadoop;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class doubleWc {
public static class doubMapper extends   Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>
{
    Text outkey=new Text();
    IntWritable outvalue=new IntWritable();
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String []cols=values.toString().split(",");
        for(int i=0;i<(cols.length) - 1 ;i++)
        {
            outkey.set(cols[i]+","+cols[i+1]);
            outvalue.set(1);
            context.write(outkey, outvalue);
        }
    }
}
public static class douReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>
{
    IntWritable outvalue=new IntWritable();
    public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(IntWritable t:values)
        {
            sum=sum+t.get();
        }
        outvalue.set(sum);
        context.write(key, outvalue);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf=new Configuration();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Job job=new Job(conf,"double program");

    job.setJarByClass(doubleWc.class);
    job.setMapperClass(doubMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(douReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?1:0);

}

}
```

PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF IT HELP!!!!

Comment: Your solution is nice. Just add some write-up explaining Map and Reduce functions :)

Comment: This code ran fine without any error but giving empty output file..!

Comment: worked fine..! after changing the mapper code as below :

Comment: public class DoubleMapper1 extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>
{
    Text outkey = new Text();
    IntWritable outvalue = new IntWritable();
    
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
     String []cols = values.toString().split("\\w+");

        for(int i=0; i<(cols.length)-1 ; i++)
        {
            String s1 = "["; String s2 = "]";
            outkey.set( s1+ cols[i]+","+cols[i+1] +s2 );
            outvalue.set(1);
            context.write(outkey, outvalue);
        }
    }
}

Comment: ya.. My input file was "," separated thats the reason i used split(","). 

Thanks